# How to write to a datagridview from a recordset?

Tags: vb.net

Working with SQL database retrieving into a record set.  Any reason you can see that this would not work?  The dataFN is the name in the datagridview and this is correct.  The messagebox shows 51,000 or so records, so the SQL command is working nicely.

Thanks in advance

```
       Dim i As Integer = 0
    rs.Open("SELECT Elig.FirstName, Elig.LastName, Elig.GroupID, CallLog.EligID, " + _
         "CallLog.DateTime, CallLog.AssignTo, CallLog.Status, CallLog.ReasonCode, " + _
         "CallLog.ReasonDesc FROM Elig INNER JOIN CallLog ON Elig.EligID = CallLog.EligID " + _
         "ORDER BY Elig.FirstName", AdoCon, rs.CursorType, rs.LockType, 0)

    MessageBox.Show("you have " + rs.RecordCount.ToString + " rows")

    While Not rs.EOF
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("DataFN").Value = rs.Fields("FirstName").Value.ToString
        rs.MoveNext()
        i += 1
    End While
```

Comment: Got it... needed to add a row before adding to the row... DUH          DataGridView1.Rows.Add()

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OleDbDataAdapter to fill a dataset from a recordset:

```
Using da as OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
  Dim ds as DataSet = New Dataset
  da.Fill(ds, rs, tableName)
End Using
```

This will create a dataset with the correct schema and data -- note that the recordset is closed (irreversible as far as i have been able to discover), so if your going to write the data back to the DB, you'll have to make your own insert/update/delete commands.

I only recommend this as an interim step on the way to using ADO.NET, but it does work to give you a workable app while you work on upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Why are not you using a dataset ?

Get your data into a dataset

and then use:

```
mygrid.datasource = mydataset.tables(0).defaultview
mygrid.refresh
```