# Total data in ms. access on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, ms-access, crud

How to display the number of students from a DataGridview in a textbox using the function

```
Public Function CountTotalItem()
Dim total As Integer
Call Connection()
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim msTotalItem As String = "select sum(Total) from Data where name='" & TextBox.5.text & "'" 
cmd = New OleDbCommand(msTotalItem, conn)
total = cmd.ExecuteScalar
Return total
End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to a datagridview from a recordset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293221/how-to-write-to-a-datagridview-from-a-recordset)

Comment: No, So my data has 4 items n I want to count the total of the item to a textbox using a function.

Comment: You show Sum function, do you really want Count? I don't use VB.net, just VBA. In Access I could call function from textbox ControlSource property and probably just use intrinsic Sum or Count function. A Sub to set Value of textbox from recordset field would be like `Me.tbxBox = rs!fieldname`. So would it be anything like that in VB.net? Review https://forums.asp.net/t/1753765.aspx?How+to+make+text+box+read+from+dataset

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097168/bind-a-textbox-to-the-sum-of-a-datatable-column

Answer (score 0):

Functions in vb.net need a return type.

```
Public Function CountTotalItem() As Integer
```

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used. They have Dispose methods which must be called to release any unmanaged objects they use. The framework provides `Using...End Using` blocks that close and dispose these objects. Get rid of the `Connectio()` method. BTW, `Call` is no longer needed.

**Always use Parameters.** Do not concatenate strings in sql statements. They may contain malicious input which can harm your database. Access doesn't care about parameter names. We use them for readability. For Access the order that the parameter appears in the sql statement must match the order that the parameter is added to the `Parameters` collection.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Public Function CountTotalItem() As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("select sum(Total) from Data where name= @Name", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
        conn.Open()
        total = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    Return total
End Function
```

You say you want Count but you are using Sum in sql statement. If you really want Count, correct the sql.